# Add css file to the Admin Theme of the Commerce Kickstart distribution?

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to add a css file to the Admin Theme (for Backend) of the Commerce Kickstart distribution.

I tried this in a custom module, but not working, the css file is not loaded at all.

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'commerce_kickstart_admin') . 'css/overrides.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'type' => 'file'));
```

I created the css file at:

```
profiles/commerce_kickstart/themes/commerce_kickstart_admin/css/overrides.css
```

Also, is there any way to put the css file in other location? like:

> site/all/themes/mytheme/css/overrides.css

Comment: Any reason not to create child theme and simply use info file to point to your CSS?

Comment: @Mołot I just need to add 3 or 4 css rules, should I create a subtheme for this?

Comment: For sure it's simpler than creating module - the same burden for system, but at least you would be using tool *designed* for that purpose. Modules are capable of doing it, but that's not what they was created for. Themes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to create a subtheme for additional CSS. That's what subthemes are for, after all, and it's less work than to make a module. Simply use info file and it's `stylesheets[all][]` entry.

If you have time, you can investigate how [AdaptiveTheme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) allows GUI editing of CSS, and implement this in your custom theme. AT is open-source after all, so it would be legal to copy-paste this functionality. It will make your life easier for future:

[image: Custom CSS screenshot]